# Sequence Use. Two Sequences on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

You can use 1 or 2 sequence.

Let's say I have a table `tblOrder` and 2 columns in it, `OrderID` and `Company`. I only use two companies in my table, `IBM` and `Airtel`.

What I want is when is `Company = IBM` then `OrderID` insert as 1 and when company is `Airtel` then it should insert `OrderID` as 1001 and repeat steps with increment 1, meaning next `OrderID` for `IBM` should be 2 and for `Airtel` should be 1002.

I think I need to use two sequences, on one column with case expression.

Comment: Yes, you need one sequence for IBM, and a second for Airtel - so what's the problem exactly?

Comment: You could go with a computed column adding 1000 to your identity ID in case of company being Airtel. But - to be honest - this smells like bad approach...

Comment: How can I bind 2 sequences on 1 column. That's the problem and how can i handle it? Please give me a working example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: more ideas:
1) You could have a VIEW with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY OrderID)` . This will always deliver a gap-less running number for each group - but maybe not the same in each call.

2) Use two separate tables each with an IDENTITY and combine them with UNION

3) Use a function to get the next ID (in an after insert trigger?)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNextID(@Company VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ISNULL((SELECT MAX(OrderID) FROM YourTable WHERE Company=@Company) + 1,0);
END
```

Hope this helps...

--old text

If your sequences don't have to be without gaps, you could try something like this:

There are other approaches (e.g. use two different tables and combine them in a UNION SELECT).

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (OrderID INT IDENTITY
                   ,Company VARCHAR(100)
                   ,ResolvedID AS CASE Company WHEN 'Airtel' THEN OrderID+1000
                                               WHEN 'Something' THEN OrderID + 2000 
                                               ELSE OrderID END);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Airtel')
                      ,('IBM')
                      ,('Something');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: Next ID when you inserting then It should insert in series. Means ResolvedID should 1001 then 1002 then 1003.... but orderid can be anything means we cant say OrderId+ 1000 that'll be wrong.

Comment: @VishalMittal, Where do you need this ID? It is - generally speaking - a bad idea to use the ID as gap less number (what happens on delete?). I'll add some ideas into my answer...